# How to form a number line in columns and rows in python using IDLE

Tags: python

How do you write a program that creates a number grid based on user inputs in python.
User will input the starting integer, number of rows, and number of columns.

I did

```
i = eval(input("Enter the starting integer:"))
r = eval(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
c = eval(input("Enter the number of columns:"))
for x in range (i):
    print(*range(i))
```

and the problem is it doesn't start with the number I enter, 
how can I fix this?

The output should be like this:
for example,

if I input  integer:6, rows:3, and columns:4
it should result:

```
6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14
15 16 17
```

Comment: How do you want to handle spacing between numbers when the number of digits gets large?

Comment: What do you mean by number grid?  Will both axis start at the same value?

Comment: What's your expected output supposed to look like? Like say I give you a starting integer of `10`, `5` rows, and `2` columns?

Comment: For example if I input integer: 6, rows: 3, columns:4 it should result:

6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14
15 16 17

Comment: Please improve your question by giving examples of expected input and expected output.

Comment: Ah, much better with an example!

Comment: Thank you, it's is my first time posting, I will improve more next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces the desired output:

```
i = eval(input("Enter the starting integer:"))
r = eval(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
c = eval(input("Enter the number of columns:"))

for y in range(c):
    for x in range(r):
        print(i,' ', end='')
        i += 1
    print()

Enter the starting integer:6
Enter the number of rows:3
Enter the number of columns:4
6  7  8  
9  10  11  
12  13  14  
15  16  17
```

*Note* the table has 4 rows of 3 columns.

Comment: Thank you! It works!! But I have a question. " end=' ' " what does this mean? I see that it makes the number appear across. How come?

Comment: That sounds like another question to be asked on StackOverflow. But, actually, don't ask the question on StackOverflow. You should do your own research: either https://stackoverflow.com or https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot!